# App using Xamarin Forms crashing randomly in iOS16 - was fine in previous versions

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

New here and new to Xamarin Forms, so please bare with me if I'm asking a silly question.

I have built an App in Xamarin Forms - it's nothing to complicated - two maps, polygraph, some videos. It works perfectly before the iOS16 update. However, since updating to iOS16 is will freeze and crash randomly - it could work fine for hours, and then will freeze and crash. Open up the app again, it may be frozen, crash and then work fine again.

On the iOS16 simulator on my machine, it works fine. However, if I debug it by putting it on my phone, it happens

Firstly does this sound like a problem anyone recognises? If not, how do I get a crash dump that might provide some explanation? I've tried updating Xamarin.Forms, Community and Newtonsoft, I've also stripped back each item off the app and it still does it on a really simple bar of five image buttons and some stacks - I'm pulling my hair out now so any advice greatly received.

J

Comment: I am also facing this same problem in real device with iOS16.

Comment: I'm slightly relived it's not just me having the problem! Mine has quite a few Stack Layouts - I've noticed I'm not getting the issue with a tabbed page with scrollviews so far.....

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug which only occurred on the ios16 devices. I will report the bug to Microsoft team. Please provide more details about the crash like which device you use, which item you use. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks. It's using a iPhone 12, I've tried but iOS16 and 16.0.02. The App is written in Xamarin.Forms.......

Comment: Thanks, I have reported this question to the Microsoft team.